# Dockerized vaadin stucked in specify part of running

Tags: java, docker, vaadin, vaadin24

I have very weird problem with dockerized vaadin. After bulding docker's image and running I get infomation as below:

```
    2023-05-27T22:55:42.959Z
    INFO
    [INFO] Couldn't find node. Installing Node and npm to /root/.vaadin.
    
    2023-05-27T22:55:42.960Z
    INFO
    [INFO] Installing node version v18.14.1
    
    2023-05-27T22:55:42.961Z
    INFO
    [INFO] Downloading https://unofficial-builds.nodejs.org/download/release/v18.14.1/node-v18.14.1-linux-x64-musl.tar.gz to /root/.vaadin/node-v18.14.1-linux-x64-musl.tar.gz
    
    2023-05-27T22:55:42.962Z
    INFO
    [INFO] No proxies configured
    
    2023-05-27T22:55:42.963Z
    INFO
    [INFO] No proxy was configured, downloading directly
    
    2023-05-27T22:55:43.623Z
    INFO
    [INFO] Unpacking /root/.vaadin/node-v18.14.1-linux-x64-musl.tar.gz (44977023 bytes) into /root/.vaadin/node/tmp
    
    2023-05-27T22:55:46.336Z
    INFO
    [INFO] Copying node binary from /root/.vaadin/node/tmp/node-v18.14.1-linux-x64-musl/bin/node to /root/.vaadin/node/bin/node
    
    2023-05-27T22:55:46.338Z
    INFO
    [INFO] Extracting npm
    
    2023-05-27T22:55:47.895Z
    INFO
    [INFO] Local node installation successful.
```

Of course it looks like regular info, but it should go on, but stuck on this part.
I've tried many times on verious enviroments such as railwayapp or render app, but problem doesnt't disapear.

Additionally, here is my dockerfile:

```
FROM maven:3.8.6-eclipse-temurin-19-alpine AS build
COPY . .
RUN mvn clean package -Pproduction


FROM eclipse-temurin:19-jre
COPY --from=build target/*.jar app.jar
EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "/app.jar"]
```

Comment: Have you tried letting it run for several minutes? The frontend build takes quite a while sometimes, especially in a container. If I recall correctly, it doesn't really output anything during that time.

Comment: If you get this error from _running_ it, it looks like you have not built it for production after all.